# how to achieve openssl smime encrypt with public key functionality in code

Tags: node.js, ruby, openssl, public-key-encryption

I am encrypting a file with this openssl command - 
`openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -in <input-file> -binary -outform DEM publicKey.pem`

Although the command uses public key but it does not uses RSA as the input file is certainly larger in size.

The same file can be decrypted by -
`cat encrypted | openssl smime -decrypt  -binary -inform DEM -inkey publickey.pem`

My question is, what method openssl uses here to encrypt using public key and how to achieve this command line functionality in code using node.js / ruby ?

Comment: [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

Comment: But where does it stores the generated symmetric key? is it part of encrypted file?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the encrypted file.

Comment: Is there a document which describes in which part of the file it stored / appended or some pointer which might help in creating the same programmatically

Comment: Yes several, but it's a freaking nightmare of pointless complexity. See [CMS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652) if you're just interested in the encrypted data format. If you are also interested in putting the right headers and so forth on it then see [S/MIME](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8551). I disapprove of these and most IETF security standards. These standards have tremendous complexity, and for 99.9% of the users this complexity buys them nothing. If I wasn't so lazy and such a nobody I would lead an effort to provide alternative standards to the IETF.